# Coffeescript is treating finally() method of promise as a property

Tags: coffeescript

The coffescript is messing up the .finall() method of the promise and making it `})["finally"](function() {` instead of calling it as a method of the promise object.

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer")
.controller "CreateNodeCtrl", ($scope, $modalInstance,
  LoadBalancerService, StatusTrackerService, NodeService) ->
  $scope.createNode = (node) ->
    $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false
    $scope.statusBar = true
    $scope.nodeStatus = "Building"
    $scope.statusType = "warning"
    LoadBalancerService.getLoadBalancer().then (loadBalancer) ->
      NodeService.createNode(
        account_number: foo
        admin_state: "enabled"
        label: node.label
        ip: node.ip
        port: node.port
        comment: node.comment
        health_strategy: {}
        vendor_extensions: {}
      ).then((eventId) ->
        $scope.disableButtonsForRun = true
        trackStatus = StatusTrackerService.runEventCheck "9936", "0fd6afd9-4aa0-a5c9-ff0b3e60cdcf"
        trackStatus.then (( ->
          $scope.statusType = "success"
          $scope.nodeStatus = "Completed Successfully"
          setTimeout ( ->
            $modalInstance.close()
            return
          ), 3000
        ), ( ->
          $scope.nodeStatus = "Failure!"
          $scope.statusType = "danger"
        ))
        .finally ->
            $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false
```

---

```
TypeError: Object function () {
        $scope.nodeStatus = "Failure!";
        return $scope.statusType = "danger";
      } has no method 'finally'
```

---

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").controller("CreateNodeCtrl", function($scope, $modalInstance, LoadBalancerService, StatusTrackerService, NodeService) {
  $scope.createNode = function(node) {
    $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false;
    $scope.statusBar = true;
    $scope.nodeStatus = "Building";
    $scope.statusType = "warning";
    return LoadBalancerService.getLoadBalancer().then(function(loadBalancer) {
      $scope.statusBar = true;
      return NodeService.createNode({
        account_number: loadBalancer.customer,
        admin_state: "enabled",
        label: node.label,
        ip: node.ip,
        port: node.port,
        comment: node.comment,
        health_strategy: {},
        vendor_extensions: {}
      }).then(function(eventId) {
        $scope.disableButtonsForRun = true;
        return StatusTrackerService.runEventCheck("9936", "0fd6afd9-7-4aa0-a5c9-ff0b3e60cdcf");
      }).then((function() {
        $scope.statusType = "success";
        return $scope.nodeStatus = "Completed Successfully";
        setTimeout((function() {
          $modalInstance.close();
        }), 3000);
      }), (function() {
        $scope.nodeStatus = "Failure!";
        return $scope.statusType = "danger";
      })["finally"](function() {
        return $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false;
      }));
    });
  };
```

Comment: Coffeescript does compile "finally" functions using this notation, but this is wanted for compatibility with ES3. Source: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3403

Answer (score 2):

You have 13 opening braces and only 12 closing.

*Maybe* an extra `(` here:

```
trackStatus.then ((
#                ^
  $scope.statusType = "success"
  $scope.nodeStatus = "Completed Successfully"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your posted indentation isn't consistent. The last line, Line 34: `$scope.disableButtonsForRun = false`, has an extra level of indention.

Try this:

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer")
.controller "CreateNodeCtrl", ($scope, $modalInstance,
  LoadBalancerService, StatusTrackerService, NodeService) ->
  $scope.createNode = (node) ->
    $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false
    $scope.statusBar = true
    $scope.nodeStatus = "Building"
    $scope.statusType = "warning"
    LoadBalancerService.getLoadBalancer().then (loadBalancer) ->
      NodeService.createNode(
        account_number: foo
        admin_state: "enabled"
        label: node.label
        ip: node.ip
        port: node.port
        comment: node.comment
        health_strategy: {}
        vendor_extensions: {}
      ).then((eventId) ->
        $scope.disableButtonsForRun = true
        trackStatus = StatusTrackerService.runEventCheck "9936", "0fd6afd9-4aa0-a5c9-ff0b3e60cdcf"
        trackStatus.then (( ->
          $scope.statusType = "success"
          $scope.nodeStatus = "Completed Successfully"
          setTimeout ( ->
            $modalInstance.close()
            return
          ), 3000
        ), ( ->
          $scope.nodeStatus = "Failure!"
          $scope.statusType = "danger"
        ))
        .finally ->
          $scope.disableButtonsForRun = false
```

Comment: This still does not compile for me using coffee script 1.7.1: `z.coffee:34:46: error: unmatched OUTDENT`

Comment: @SylvainLeroux exactly, its not clear where the `()` should end within the nested `.then()`s